# Validate set of radio buttons using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

How to validate a set of radio buttons having different name attribute.

For ex:

```
<div id="divTest">
     <ul>
          <li><input type="radio" name="rdo0"><span>Good</span></li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="rdo0"><span>Average</span></li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="rdo0"><span>Bad</span></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
          <li><input type="radio" name="rdo1"><span>Test</span></li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="rdo1"><span>Test 2</span></li>
          <li><input type="radio" name="rdo1"><span>Test 3</span></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

i want to validate that every "ul" should have a selected radio button and get appropriate message in either case.

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try by yourself...

Anyway, here is an example :

```
function validate_checkbox() {
    var error = false;
    $('ul', '#divTest').each(function() {
        if ( $('input[type="radio"]:checked', this).length == 0) {
            error = true;
        }
    });    
    return error;
}

$("#somebutton").on('click', function() {
        alert(validate_checkbox() ? 'error' : 'ok');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/mgjwj/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var radioChecked = false;
$("ul.ContainsRadios").each(function(ind,ele){
    radioChecked = false;
    $(ele).children("input[type=radio]").each(function(ind2,ele2) {
        if (ele2.checked){
             radioChecked = true;
        }
    });
    if(!radioChecked){
       $(ele).addClass("ValidatClass");
    }
});
```

the only issue with the above code is you will need to label the UL's that contain the radio inputs, with something like the class i mention in the code.

Comment: name attribute is generated dynamically, so i want a solution which does not include hard coded values.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have radio buttons:

```
var $uls = $('#divTest > ul');
if ($uls.find(':checked').length === $uls.length) {
   // is valid
```

If you have other inputs too then it's `.find(':radio:checked')`